# Pass UserID to model using Devise/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using `Rails 4.0` and the `devise gem` for user authentication. I have a base user model setup using the `devise` default scaffolding.

Each of my users has an `id`, and I want to pass that `id` to other tables. What is the best way to get that `id` so that I can do that? I want something like `current_user.id`, but I don't know how to define `current_user`. Does devise provide something like this by default?

Comment: you cannot pass the id to another tables, you can create a foreign key in your tables that references the user id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Devise will make the `current_user` helper method available in your controllers and views when you add `before_filter :authenticate_user!` to your controller.

This is explained in more detail in the docs [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers).